# 13.04 always prompts for network password on startup

Tags: 13.04, wireless, network-manager, password

This is a recent issue. Whenever I start up my laptop, it will attempt to automatically connect to my school network (WPA2-Enterprise) as it should. However, it prompts me for the password on the login screen every time (unless I log in before it is able to attempt the connection). I have checked/tried the following

- `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` has root read-write permissions.
- 'All users may connect to this network' is checked in the network's settings by default, and I have unchecked, saved, and rechecked just to make sure.
- The (correct) password is indeed saved in the network settings

I've noted that there is no problem attempting to manually/automatically connect when I have already logged in. I even logged in and back out and then switched the wireless on and off, and it didn't have an issue connecting again. Any advice?

edit; I previously thought this was a general issue with all networks, however I believe it only occurs when connecting to my school's WPA2-Enterprise network, not my WEP personal router.

Comment: I have the same issue, so far there is no fix yet. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1158432

Comment: Check out this bug on Launchpad [On graphical login, Network Manager window gets in the way](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1158432).  Is this the problem you have? If yes mark the bug as affecting you too.  The more people a bug affects the more priority the developers will give to fixing it.

Comment: It sounds about the same so I'll mark the bug. However it only affects one network, which has WPA2-Enterprise security, so it certainly isn't universal. I'll stay tuned for workarounds.